# Similarity between 2 Lines in 2D

Tags: math, geometry, line

I cant find a similar question here on SO. I have two lines l1 and l2, defined by 2 sets of 2D points each.

I don't care about the position of the points, just the entire line itself. I need a metric for similarity between the 2 lines. I tried to use y=mx+c, but of course if the line is pointing up, then m goes to infinity, and so does c.

So what can I do about this? I could convert them both to parametric form, but what do I do after that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have lines' formula, you can use the [**cosine similarity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

Moreover, if you want to find the similarity between two segments (not the line), you can use [**Frechet Distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance).

Comment: doesnt that only handle the orientation of the line..not the position of it? So two parallel lines would give the max similarity despite not lying on the same location

Comment: i have the parametric form of the line

Comment: The line has not positioned! Its ends are infinity.

Comment: i am aware of that..but if two parallel lines are closer to each other..it should give a lower score. And i dont want to deal with line segments, i want the full line to infinity